# Bash terminal does not recognize a path in a variable because of the "~"

Tags: bash, variables, find, pathname

For example if I type ~ or ~/Documents as an input I get the message : No such file or directory

However if I use /home/username/Documents it works fine.

```
echo "Dose onoma katalogou"

read Directory

find $Directory -type f -perm 777
```

Any idea on why this happens and how I could fix it in order to be able to type pathnames including "~"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash expands the variable $Directory [after](http://bashrules.blogspot.de/2006/04/bash-order-of-expansions.html) it expands any ~, thus once $Directory is expanded, the time to expand ~ has passed.

```
eval find $Directory -type f -perm 777
```

will work because eval will see the ~ and run shell expansion again.

You may test the effect by simpler commands:

```
tilde='~'
echo $tilde            # prints a literal ~
eval echo $tilde       # prints your home directory
```

By the way, a directory names containing blanks will cause problems.

Comment: Beware: `eval` is a very powerful mechanism — and very dangerous if the user controls the contents of `$Directory`.  For example, if the user gets `Directory='$(rm -f $HOME &)'` into the `eval` command, someone will be very unhappy — especially if the script is run by `root`.